# Not getting result when using StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter and related library

Tags: java, maven, configuration, struts2

When I am using `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` and related library which are

`commons-fileupload-1.3.jar, commons-io-2.2.jar, commons-lang-3.1.jar, commons-logging-1.1.3.jar, commons-logging-api-1.1.jar, freemarker-2.3.19.jar, javassist-.3.11.0.GA, ognl-3.0.6.jar, struts2-core-2.3.16.jar, xwork-core.2.3.16.jar`

The result I am getting is `The requested resource is not available.`
`web.xml` file is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

   <display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
      </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

But when I am using FilterDispatcher and related library which are

`commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar, commons-io-1.3.2.jar, commons-lang-2.4.jar, commons-logging-1.0.4.jar, freemarker-2.3.8.jar, javassist, ognl-2.7.3.jar, struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar, xwork-core.2.1.6.jar`

Then I am getting the desire result.
web.xml file is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
   id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

   <display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
      </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I don't know where I am getting wrong.
Can somebody please tell me where i am getting wrong or what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `commons-lang-2.4.jar` is missing in the first library set. Another important dependency is `commons-lang3-3.1.jar`. If you use Maven project configuration you don't ned to configure libraries manually. Because `struts2-core` artifact include all those dependencies.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>X.X.X.X</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Sir but i am using commons-lang-3.1.jar in first library. or I have to use commons-lang-2.4.jar insted of commons-lang-3.1.jar

Comment: Sir can you please tell me reason for using both        commons-lang-2.4.jar and commons-lang-3.1.jar. I  am not using Maven Project configuration.

Comment: the reason is some other libraries depend on it, another one use newer api.

Comment: Thank You sir for explanation.